# Starter Theme Prestashop 1.7 is blank

Tags: php, ubuntu, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I've installed PS 1.7 on local ubuntu env with php 5.6 and I wanted to check out starter theme, but it isn't working.

Could it be some permissions problem or what? Default theme works no sweat.

Here's topic on prestashop forums for more detailed information: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/573994-cant-get-starter-theme-to-work/

Comment: I know that the 1.7 have problems with php < 7, have you tried with php >= 7?

Comment: I'll try to switch to 1.7 and let you know.

Comment: Ok but I says PHP version not the PrestaShop version :)

Comment: I switched to 7, and set everything one more time. Still there's no change (I updated topic on prestashop forums)

Comment: I don't understand why do you do all those things, npm, nodejs, etc...

Comment: That's what it says in the Starter Theme guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The StarterTheme you found on GitHub is a dev version, it's meant to be the bare minimum of your project.

In `config` folder you'll find a `theme.dist.yml` file. The very first step is to rename this file `theme.yml` and edit it.

You can change the display name key if you want. The most important one is the `name` key. It has to be the theme directory name.
See: http://developers.prestashop.com/themes/gettingstarted/index.html#theme-yml

Julien

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Cache folder inside theme/assets exists. If not create it and and 7777 permissions on it. You should see the theme now